# How to display Realm object in ListFragment on Android?

Tags: android, realm

I have an application with listFragments and i want to display data from Realm into them in a porper way.
For example i have Users with lot of datas (name, favourite sports etc...)

User class:

```
public class User extends RealmObject {
@PrimaryKey
private long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private RealmList<UserSport> sports = new RealmList<>();
private RealmList<User> friends= new RealmList<>();
private RealmList<User> sportmates= new RealmList<>();
{and some other, and getters and setters} 
}
```

The user can choose the "users" menu in which there are 3 ListFragments in different tabs (Friends, Sportmates, Others)

Friends fragment:

```
public class FriendsFragment extends ListFragment {
List<User> users;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup    container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_team, container, false);
    users=new ArrayList<>();           
        long userid=/*The currently logged in users id.*/
        Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(getContext());
        users.addAll(realm.where(User.class).equalTo("id",userid).findFirst().getFriends());
    MySportmateListAdapter adapter = new   MySportmateListAdapter(getContext(), users);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    final ListView listView = getListView();
    final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
    // swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener();
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        //TODO implement
    });
    listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            int topRowVerticalPosition = (listView == null || listView.getChildCount() == 0) ? 0 : listView.getChildAt(0).getTop();
            swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(firstVisibleItem == 0 && topRowVerticalPosition >= 0);
        }

    });
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Here is " + position + ". item " + v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

MyListAdapter that extends from baseadapter (and implements filterable, but it for other usage of it so it isn't neccessary now):

```
package teammeup.com.teammeup.ListAdapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit.Call;
import retrofit.JacksonConverterFactory;
import retrofit.Retrofit;
import teammeup.com.teammeup.API.RestService;
import teammeup.com.teammeup.R;
import teammeup.com.teammeup.domain.User;

public class MySportmateListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {


Context context;
List<User> users;
ListFragment parentFragment;

public MySportmateListAdapter(Context context, List<User> users) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.users = users;
}
/*This is for the other usage!*/
public MySportmateListAdapter(Context context, ListFragment fragment) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    parentFragment=fragment;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return users.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return users.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return users.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_on_list, parent, false);
    }
User user = users.get(position);
   /*Here are some textviews and other for a custom layout... and I sett hem with the datas from the user.*/   

    convertView.setTag(user.getId());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
       /*For other usage, so it not neccessary now*/


    return filter;
}
```

}

So my problem is that I want to use that adapter for the Sportmates and the Others fragments, which are nearly the same, but with different datas. I think I have to pass the datas to the adapter from the ListFragments in this case.

My question is, how to handle the realm in a porper way? Where to Open/Close it? I have a logout option on the menu, where I want to delete all datas (the whole Realm).

I think onResume/onPause open/close won't work, because of the logout.

I use the slidingtablayout for the tabs, and if I am right it prepares the fragmnets near the opened fragment, so 1 more reason against the onResume/onPause open/close.

Can you help me please, to do it in the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just recently added a best practise section to our docs about controlling the Realm lifecycle: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#best-practices

Instead of trying to delete the Realm file on logout, you can also just remove all the data in the Realm by doing something like described here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1796